# Levin Lin Chu test in Stata

Tags: stata, panel-data

I need to do a unit root test with my panel data. I have 1500 firms from 98-2000. I want to examine if my `LOGwage` variable has unit roots or not. When I `xtset` my panel by firm and year, Stata said that it's strongly balanced. But when I do the test `xtunitroot llc wage if FirmID`, it gives me `"Levin-Lin-Chiu test requires strongly balanced data"`?

Comment: Btw: The test is called Levin–Lin–Chu ( Levin–Lin–Chu (2002)), not  Levin–Lin–Chiu even if it seems the error message by Stata contains a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  Fisher-type unit-root test which is based on augmented Dickey-Fuller tests.
Stata command for the test is following:

```
xtunitroot fisher varname, dfuller lag(1)
```